# Uma imagem grande atrapalha no desempenho da aplicação?

Tags: html5, img

Meu banner tem uma imagem de 11mb, enquanto local está tudo ok, mas gostaria de saber se quando subir esta aplicação irá deixar a mesma pesada.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tudo que o navegador vai precisar baixar "atrapalha" a aplicação, quanto mais arquivos e mais pesados esse arquivos forem, mais lento pra carregar

Comment: Complementando o que @DanielCosta comentou... Lembre-se que atualmente acessamos páginas web pelo Mobile e que geralmente possuem uma conexão 3g. Imagina o quão custoso seria para esse usuário abrir sua página já que só seu Banner é do tamanho de um App.

Comment: Obrigado galera, pensarei nisso e escolhei a melhor maneira para tal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Brasil, a [velocidade média da internet móvel gira em torno de `2 Mbps`](http://www.idec.org.br/pdf/analise-internet-movel-brasil-2g-3g.pdf), isso resulta em uma taxa de download de aproximadamente `256 KB/s`. Sua imagem pesa `11 MB`, isso levaria aproximadamente `44 segundos` para baixar apenas sua imagem.

Mesmo para uma internet de `15 Mbps`, o download da imagem demoraria aproximadamente `6 segundos`, o que ainda assim pode ser considerado demorado.

Você pode verificar o desempenho da sua aplicação por alguns websites. Segue uma lista:

- [Think with Google](https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/)
- [Varvy](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/)
- [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Alguns artigos sobre otimização de imagens:

- [Otimização de imagens - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization)
- [10 Must Know Image Optimization Tips - Shopify Blog (Inglês)](https://www.shopify.com/blog/7412852-10-must-know-image-optimization-tips)

Answer (score 2):

Lembre-se que não desenvolvemos mais apenas para plataforma PC, dar suporte para celulares e tablets é extremamente importante.

A questão das imagens é um tópico importante do design responsivo. Imagina que tem gente por aí que acessa a sua página através do plano de dados. No brasil vamos achar planos de 600mb, 400mb até de 200mb.

Se o seu site com uma imagem é capaz de consumir 5% de uma franquia, isso certamente é um problema.

Otimize a sua imagem para web.